# Background Image incorreto em IPhone

Tags: css

Estou usando:

```
    <section class="parallax calltoaction section_padding_100"
    style="
        background-image: url('images/models_cover/landscapes.jpg');
        background-size:100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    ">
```

Ao acessar pelo chrome, firefox e safari via desktop funciona perfeitamente como na imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao acessar via navegador Android Chrome, funciona perfeitamente também.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, ao acessar via iPhone com o navegador padrão ou Chrome, fica da seguinte forma.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já troquei o `background-size:`  por `cover` e `container`, mas, fica na mesma.

Comment: Tentou apenas "cover" ou "100% cover"?

Comment: Opa @Perozzo, sim amigão, já testou com o cover, o 100% cover, e o container. Dá no mesmo

Comment: Tem como informar os outros atributos CSS dessa `<section>`? Talvez o problema esteja neles e não no background.

Comment: É muito difícil de identificar o problema sem poder verificar eu mesmo em um iPhone. Mas algumas pesquisas por aqui podem sugerir algumas soluções. Precisaria checar melhor o CSS, mas como você está usando parallax, imagino que essa imagem de fundo deva estar recebendo: `background-attachment: fixed;` que vi que pode causar problemas no iOS.  Tenta colocar um `background-attachment: scroll;` e checa o resultado.

Comment: Não tenho Iphone pra testar. Mas olha essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21456799/2570426

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que dá para ver no seu HTML, você está usando uma classe chamada parallax. Provavelmente essa classe está usando o atributo `background-attachment: fixed`, pois é através dessa propriedade que se faz o efeito mais simples de parallax.

O que acontece é que esse tipo de efeito não é performático em dispositivos móveis, normalmente smartphones, e a maioria dos navegadores desabilitam-o por padrão. Porém, em dispositivos com iOS ocorre o erro descrito por você, que ao invés de desabilitar a propriedade `background-attachment` com o valor `fixed`, ele faz uma espécie de zoom que não é o esperado por nós.

A solução que pode ser feita no caso de uma página responsiva, onde se deseja obter o efeito de parallax no desktop e desabilitar no mobile, é através de JavaScript, modificar o valor do atributo `background-attachment: fixed` para `scroll` em todos os elementos que utilizem a classe `.parallax`. Ou então, se você se baseia em resolução para saber se é mobile ou desktop, você pode definir isso em um  media query no CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta com o seguinte codigo, funcionou perfeitamente na minha aplicação

```css
html {
    background: url(http://placebear.com/1200/800) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body{
    height:100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```